# Django styling login forms and adding additional spans

Tags: css, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I have two questions in form-styling.

1. For my login, I am using Django's default auth features and haven't written any views or forms manually.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.contrib.auth.views',

    url(r'^login/$','login',
    {'template_name':'login.html'},
    name='qna_login'),

    url(r'^logout/$','logout',
    {'next_page':'qna_home'},
    name='qna_logout'),
    )
```

login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content%}
{% if form.errors %}
<p class="text-warning"> Your username and/or password didn't match </p>
{% endif%}
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
<div class="form-group">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

How do I add bootstrap styling to it?

2. For new user registration, I have added some bootstrap specific styles, but need to add  additional spans and replace the labels with Glyphicons.

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Username'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Email'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Password'})
```

What I need to do is replace what is generated in the template, such as

```
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input class="form-control" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" /> <span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters</span></p>
```

by a custom bootstrap addon and glyphicon, like

```
<div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#b77b48; color:white"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile to take a look on how Django renders its login form: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can render each field individually instead of letting Django render the whole form with `{{ form }}`. You can write the template like this -

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#b77b48; color:white"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                <input class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" maxlength="30" name="{{ field.html_name }}" value="{{ field.value }}" type="text" /> 
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

As always, like everything else, [Django documentation has everything](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template).

Comment: Thank you, this answers my second question but this doesn't apply the bootstrap styling to the input box itself. I used this to style the rest of the form. How do I add a CSS classes  and placeholders to {{ form.username }} and {{ form.password }} etc. Please note that I don't have a forms.py or view defined for my login as it is provided by django.contrib.auth. I couldn't find a way in the docs.

Comment: If you read the doc, you can further modify the fields. The only thing django backend needs is the input field name. You can even use a static form.

Comment: Updated answer example.

Comment: To access the filed elements independently (without a for loop) use:     {{ form.username.html_name }}

Comment: using `type="text"` for password field will display the types password as text so iteration through the fields of the form may not be a good idea. It is better to specify fields one by one specifically. for password field `type="password"` is required to hide the typed text.

Comment: where should i used the variable name in <input attributes > ?? name or id ?

Comment: A password field should be hidden. Adding `type="text"` is so wrong!

Comment: [For Django >= 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.widget_type), you can use `type="{{ field.widget_type }}"' , wich will result in more correct form types (`text`, `password`....).