# Django Bootstrap input-group-addon on Model Form without separating fields

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm currently rendering my Django form in the following way:

```
<form action="/student/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Launch" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

I have multiple fields of different types, with different things applied to each field, such as validators and help-text.

I have two fields that I would like to add bootstrap spans to. One money field which I'd like to prepend a pound symbol to, and one percentage field which I'd like to append a percentage symbol to, I know that this is possible to do using bootstrap as follows:

[This input field.](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/1/)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"/>
</div>
```

But to do this in my django template would require me to break up the form into specific fields and create field specific html. Such as the solution to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729217/django-styling-login-forms-and-adding-additional-spans) proposes.

What I'm looking for is a way to specify either in the model, or the modelform, an attribute or class which will only apply to a specific field, but will render it as above without breaking up the form.

Thank you.

Info:
Bootstrap-4
Django-2.0.2
Python-3.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inherit from Base Widget. If you use the template below, you can easily create your custom bootstrap groups.

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Widget
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class PrependWidget(Widget):
    """ Widget that prepend boostrap-style span with data to specified base widget """

    def __init__(self, base_widget, data, *args, **kwargs):
        u"""Initialise widget and get base instance"""
        super(PrependWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base_widget = base_widget(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = data

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        u"""Render base widget and add bootstrap spans"""
        field = self.base_widget.render(name, value, attrs)
        return mark_safe((
            u'<div class="input-group mb-3">'
            u'  <div class="input-group-prepend">'
            u'    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">%(data)s</span>'
            u'  </div>'
            u'  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">'
            u'</div>'
        ) % {'field': field, 'data': self.data})

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    example_field = forms.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=1, label='', required=False,
                              widget=PrependWidget(base_widget=forms.TextInput, data='$'))
```

[Source](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2826/)

Answer (score -1):

In the form what you can do:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea

class MyForm(modelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            "name": TextInput({"class": "form-control"}),
            "comment": Textarea({"data-validation": "validate"}),
        }
```

You can read about widgets and learn different ways of adding custom attributes here in this link, a django doc about widgets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/